# How do I show a page update as new with a yellow star in html

Tags: html, symbols

I have added a new page to my basic html site. I want to put a yellow star with a border and text in saying NEW on the contents list, so that people can see at a glance what has changed. But nothing I try works. The best I have managed is a yellow question mark! Help! Please!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of approaches you can take. For example:
- A picture of a star will work as an inline embed
- Or you can use wingdings to create a star symbol and enclose it with div tags and add a css class to control the border and looks you want.

If you can be more specific about the approach you want to take and why, people will be able to help you more easily.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.star-5-points {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0;
  border: 100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 70px solid #000;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(35deg)   ;
  transform: rotateZ(35deg)   ;
}

.star-5-points::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -45px;
  left: -65px;
  border: 30px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 80px solid #000;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  text-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-35deg)   ;
  transform: rotateZ(-35deg)   ;
}

.star-5-points::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 3px;
  left: -105px;
  border: 100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 70px solid #000;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: red;
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  text-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-70deg)   ;
  transform: rotateZ(-70deg)   ;
}

.star-5-points > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: -36px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotateZ(-35deg);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-5-points"><span>NEW</span></div>
```

Well here you have a basic example that I built with http://enjoycss.com/code/. Play around with the values and you should be good to go for your need.

Answer (score -1):

I don't currently have a css sheet, it's just straight html. It was built a long time ago! I will rebuild it one day from scratch, but at the moment, I just need a bodge that will work direct into html and give me a star with a border around it, preferably yellow in the middle, and, if possible, with the word New inside it.